# Heap error in fibonacci exercise

Tags: java

I was given a simple task of writing a program that will find all fibonacci's numbers from given file and than return the biggest and the smallest.
Unfortunately while trying to execute an Java heap space error. 
I really don’t have clue where is the mistake, so can you help me a little?
And how to avoid repeating same mistake in the future.

```
    package maturaWielkanoc;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Zad4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(0);
        list.add(1);
        int counter = 1;
        while (list.get(list.size() - 1) < 908589244) {
            //908589244 is one bigger than the biggest number in dane.txt
            list.add(list.get(counter) + list.get(counter));
        }
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dane.txt"))) {
            String line;
            List<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<>();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                int value = Integer.parseInt(line);

                if (list.contains(value)) {
                    answer.add(value);
                }
            }
            answer.sort(null);
            System.out.println("Min = " + answer.get(0));
            System.out.println("Max = " + answer.get(answer.size() - 1));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not incrementing the counter and also you are adding the same elements list.get(counter-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your applications will run with a fixed amount of memory while a `List` will store and hold the data in memory continuously filling it up. You will continue to add the Integers to the list with no end in sight.

A quick google shows that a boxed integer is 8 bytes, your upper bound is `908589244` number of integers. Instead, let's imagine you try to store 1 billion integers, that's 8 gigs, which will quickly full up your heap.

This task is clearly a lesson on memory management. You will want to find a better way of holding the data and maintaining what is the biggest and smallest fibonacci numbers without storing them all in memory (consider evaluating each while you read each value from the file instead of adding to a list).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having every number in the list (you're likely running out of memory) store the largest number you have seen and the smallest number you have seen, and if the number read from the file is larger than the largest replace it, and smaller than the smallest:

```
int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

while(read integers from file){
  int numberFromFile = Integer.parseInt(fromFile);
  if(numberFromFile > largest){
    largest = numberFromFile;
  }
  if(numberFromFile < smallest){
    smallest = numberFromFile;
  }
}

// Now you have largest and smallest without a huge list.
```